# Stop further code from executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a request:

```
  Character.count({'character.ownerid': msg.author.id}, function (err, count) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    if (count > 3) {
      err.message = 'Too many characters';
      //create error explanation and throw it
      throw err;
    }
  })
```

If any of there errors do happen I need to exit the whole parent function. I can't put a return in this request since it exits only this method. I thought there is a possibility to do a callback like:

```
Character.count({'character.ownerid': msg.author.id}, function (err, count, stop) {
```

But how to work with it? It is inside an anonymous function, I don't know where to place its contents. I also tried to use `try`/`catch` but I can't throw errors to the outside handler because of `Error: Unhandled "error" event. ([object Object])`, see code below:

```
Character.count({'character.ownerid': msg.author.id}, function (err, count) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  if (count > 3) {
    var err = {};
    err.message = 'Too many characters';
    throw err;
  }
}).then((count) => {
  console.log('all good we may continue');
  console.log(count);
}).catch((err) => {
  if (err != undefined && err.length > 0) {
    msg.reply(err.message);
    return 0; //exit parent function?
  }
});
```

But even if this worked I am not sure if this code will do what I need. The request is asynchronous so what if the rest of the code gets triggered before `then`? Is that even possible?

So I basically need to `return 0;` the parent function somehow and if there are any errors I need to have a handler for them. Any ideas for this?

Comment: [`Character.count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#count_count) returns a "Promise" natively. There is no need for a callback inside it. Just `Character.count().then(...` and do your `if (count ..` stuff inside the `then()` instead. The documentation could be clearer, but it does say `returns <Query>` and that `Query` object actually as a `then()`. Alternately do `Character.count().exec().then(....).catch(...)` as a "full" returned Promise.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Official documentation states this: `Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for co and async/await as a convenience. If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function.`. I am not sure what that means honestly, but it doesn't seem to be a full-working promise. 2nd of all, I still don't understand how to exit the parent function on error. Catch doesn't work here, put everything inside `then`? It doesn't seem right for some reason, is it?

Comment: I know, since I linked to it. You probably did not read the full comment since I edited it after the initial submission. You don't actually "need" the `exec()` and it's optional. I know because I do this all the time, and it's exactly the reason why `let count = await Character.count()` also works with `async/await` syntax.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Yup, I didn't see the update. Well, I still have a problem, even with `exec` I can't `throw` errors for catch to handle them and will that `return` inside `catch` even exit the parent function? I feel like it won't since it is inside an anonymous function. So I guess the only solution you want to suggest is to put all the following code inside `then`, right?

Comment: I want to clarify what this is. This code is part of a much bigger script. It just checks if there is any space left for user to create new characters. If there is no space left - exit, if there is still some just continue with the script. So that's why I want it to actually exit the parent function instead of moving all the other code inside `then`, this will keep code much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the concept. Firstly as already stated, all mongoose operations return a Promise or at least a "Promise like" object which can immediately be resolved via a `then()` instead of passing in a callback function. This can either present in two ways.

Either with `async/await` syntax and a `try..catch` block:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const characterSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const Character = mongoose.model('Character', characterSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2));

const doCount = async () => {
  let count = await Character.count();

  if (count > 3)
    throw new Error("too many charaters");

  return count;

};


(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()))

    await Character.insertMany(
      ["Huey","Duey","Louie"].map(name => ({ name }))
    );

    let count = await doCount();
    log({ count });

    await Character.create({ name: 'Donald' });

    let newCount = await doCount();
    console.log("never get here");


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

Or with standard `then()` and `catch()` syntax:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const characterSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const Character = mongoose.model('Character', characterSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2));

function doCount() {
  return Character.count()
    .then(count =>  {

      if (count > 3)
        throw new Error("too many charaters");

      return count;
    });

};


(function() {

  mongoose.connect(uri)
    .then(conn => Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove())
    ))
    .then(() => Character.insertMany(
      ["Huey","Duey","Louie"].map(name => ({ name }))
    ))
    .then(() => doCount())
    .then(count => log({ count }))
    .then(() => Character.create({ name: 'Donald' }))
    .then(() => doCount())
    .then(() => console.log("never get here"))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
    .then(() => mongoose.disconnect() );

})()
```

And the output of both listings is just the same:

```
Mongoose: characters.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: characters.insertMany([ { _id: 5b0f66ec5580010efc5d0602, name: 'Huey', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5b0f66ec5580010efc5d0603, name: 'Duey', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5b0f66ec5580010efc5d0604, name: 'Louie', __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: characters.count({}, {})
{
  "count": 3
}
Mongoose: characters.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5b0f66ec5580010efc5d0605"), name: 'Donald', __v: 0 })
Mongoose: characters.count({}, {})
Error: too many charaters
    at doCount (/home/projects/characters/index.js:20:11)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

As you can see the function happily returns it's value where the `count` remains 3 or under, but then throws an exception which stops further execution when the `count` would be greater than 3 since the `"never get here"` message never gets logged.

So there is no need for "callbacks" here and you would not use one unless you wrapped it in a Promise can did the same type of error handling anyway.

But if you have an "error" then `throw` the error. This works fine in a promise chain, but a "callback" which does not return as a Promise is simply not part of that chain and can never be "caught". So simply don't use the callback when you don't need to.

Just for kicks, wrapping a callback with a Promise would be done like:

```
function doCount() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
    Character.count().exec((err,count) => {

      if (count > 3)
        reject(new Error("too many charaters"));

      resolve(count);
    })
  );
};
```

But it's noted not to be necessary considering the native methods return something you can resolve as a Promise anyway.

Comment: Well, so basically you want me to move all the code inside, so I was kinda right about that. Your code was very difficult to understand, its too professional for me :) Even tho I managed to use it in my code I still don't fully understand what this line `await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()))` means. Is this a listener on promises to remove them every time they aren't needed anymore?

Comment: @Telion Don't worry about that stuff as it's simply there to "clean up" a collection before inserting some data. The main point is I just insert 3 things and the function works fine, and then with something that would break the `if` you `throw` the error. Works fine with promises and if you actually did have a need to wrap a legacy API method with only callback arguments, then you similarly wrap in a Promise to instead receive the `reject()` response.

Comment: @Telion I also has nothing to do with "moving the code". You can "inline" anything that returns a promise. I just created an external function because "In demonstration" I am calling that function more than once, and therefore not repeating the code. The point is that what you attempted with a callback and your presumptions were both incorrect, and this gives you a correct pattern in example.

Comment: No, I am talking about all other code that won't be executed. Also, I am not sure if that's an error. So you add 3 documents freely, then you check, everything is correct since there is exactly 3 docs, you add another, 4th document(it shouldn't be possible) and after that, it breaks because 4>3. It should be >=3 in there. Other than that everything is nice, I appreciate your work and nice explanations!